# I can't add a logo to my website. It takes up the entire page. Please help me

Tags: html, css, navbar

HTML

```
<body>
  <!-- Header -->
   
  <section id="header">
    <div class="header container">
        
        
      <div class="nav-bar">
        <div class="brand">
          <a href="#home">
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-list">
          
          <div class="hamburger">
            <div class="bar"></div>
          </div>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#home" data-after="Home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#services" data-after="Service">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about" data-after="About">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact" data-after="Contact">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
```

I'm trying to add a logo to my website. The logo fills the screen. I can't adjust its size.HTML codes like this.

Comment: And where is your logo in that code?

Comment: Sorry. I am new here. I wrote old codes. I add it like this but it doesn't work.

Comment: Take some small steps and start learning from the basics it may help you understand basic workflow

Comment: Please do not post code in comments. Instead [edit] your question and change the code. And please post a [mre], meaning you should also add the `<head>` section and your css.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to answer without seeing the stylings and I see you haven't provided a proper code.

Just give the `img` tag a width and a height and position the `div` wrapping it correctly.

Something like this,

```css
div {
    position:relative;
    text-align:center;/* Add This*/
}
```

```html
<div>
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/img_girl.jpg" width='300px' height='400px'/>
</div>
```

I suggest you to refer the following,

[Positioning a div](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp) 
[Inserting an img](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_images.asp)

Good luck mate!

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I handled it.I thought of something more complex.